# Nhibernate 3.2 mapping by code. When we create a bag relation, what mean rm.OneToMany?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I use nhibernate 3.2 mapping by code and I've a strange behaviour.

If I simplify my project, I have 2 tables :

```
[Serializable]
public class Intervention
{
    public Intervention()
    {
        ReponsePointVerification = new List<ReponsePointVerification>();
    }

    #region Public Properties
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual IList<ReponsePointVerification> ReponsePointVerification
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class InterventionMap : ClassMapping<Intervention>
{
    public InterventionMap()
    {
        Id<int>(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Generator(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Generators.Identity);
        });
        Bag(x => x.ReponsePointVerification, map =>
        {
            map.Key( k => k.Column( "IdIntervention" ) );
        }); 
    }
}
```

and

```
[Serializable]
public class ReponsePointVerification
{
    #region Public Properties
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual Intervention Intervention
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ReponsePointVerificationMap : ClassMapping<ReponsePointVerification>
{
    public ReponsePointVerificationMap()
    {
        Id<int>(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Generator(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Generators.Identity);
        });
        ManyToOne<Intervention>(x => x.Intervention, map => map.Column("IdIntervention"));
    }
}
```

which represents two tables Intervention and ReponsePointVerification which has a foreign key (IdIntervention) which is linked to Intervention.

When I call :

```
        return (from interv in Session.Query<Intervention>()
                .Fetch(rep => rep.ReponsePointVerification)
                select interv).ToList();
```

or even when I don't fetch the information. I has this error :

```
Could not cast the value in field id0_ of type Int32 to the Type SerializableType.  Please check to make sure that the mapping is correct and that your DataProvider supports this Data Type.
```

The sql query looks to be ok.

I found that post http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/ef137c3e5b66acdc

And I modify the InterventionMap class according to that post it will work :

```
public class InterventionMap : ClassMapping<Intervention>
{
    public InterventionMap()
    {
        Id<int>(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Generator(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Generators.Identity);
        });
        Bag(x => x.ReponsePointVerification, map =>
        {
            map.Key( k => k.Column( "IdIntervention" ) );
        }, rm => rm.OneToMany()); 
    }
}
```

The only difference is the add of ", rm => rm.OneToMany()"

Trust me I'm very happy it worked but I really don't understand that line can someone explain me the meaning ?

Regards

**Edit**

I made a WriteAllXmlMapping and the 2 codes are :

**version without rm => rm.OneToMany() (which doesn't work)**

```
<bag name="ReponsePointVerification">
  <key column="IdIntervention" />
  <element type="Hyma.BusinessObjets.ReponsePointVerification" />
</bag>
```

**version with rm => rm.OneToMany() (which work)**

```
<bag name="ReponsePointVerification">
  <key column="IdIntervention" />
  <one-to-many class="ReponsePointVerification" />
</bag>
```

Comment: The third parameter defines the relation that mapped collection takes part in. Generally there should be no difference as `OneToMany` is the default, AFAIK. Try generating the XML mappings (`WriteAllXmlMapping` method) to see if there is any difference.

Comment: thank you for your tip, it is simplier with xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OneToMany` tells NH that this is a one-to-many relationship to another mapped entity. if left blank NH takes `ElementCollection` as default which is a one-to-many relationship to some ElementType without an id.

for example when you have these classes

```
class Parent
{
    public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }  <- one-to-many collection
    public ICollection<string> Names { get; set; }  <- element collection
}

class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then NH would create these 3 tables

```
ParentTable
id

ChildTable
id | parent_id | name

NamesTable
parent_id | name
```

or vice versa, when you have the 3 Tables, it would be reasonable to map it to the classes

Comment: If I understand you. If I map the whole database into mappings (and the table contains some id), I have to use OneToMany ? I am good ?